# Commerce Billy PDF

Tags: commerce

I'm using Commerce Billy to send an invoice PDF to my customers. When I watch the module page of Billy I see that the customer information is found on the left of the invoice...but when I make my own invoice the customer information is nowhere to find? Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to find an option for this in the module UI in de drupal back-end but I can't find anything? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Joost

Comment: TRY ctrl+p in admin side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, looking at the comment I can see that my question wasn't very clear. So what I meant was that the billing information wasn't displayed on the PDF.

The problem was that there wasn't any billing information. In the Customer Profile Types of Commerce I didn't ask for a name or organisation. I now enabled these options and the billing information is displayed on the PDF.